# Java escape HTML - string replace slow?

Tags: java

I have a Java application that makes heavy use of a large file, to read, process and give through to SolrEmbeddedServer (http://lucene.apache.org/solr/).

One of the functions does basic HTML escaping:

```
private String htmlEscape(String input)
{
    return input.replace("&", "&amp;").replace(">", "&gt;").replace("<", "&lt;")
        .replace("'", "&apos;").replaceAll("\"", "&quot;");
}
```

While profiling the application, the program spends roughly 58% of the time in this function, a total of 47% in replace, and 11% in replaceAll.

Now, is the Java replace that slow, or am I on the right path and should I consider the program efficient enough to have its bottleneck in Java and not in my code? (Or am I replacing wrong?)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For html escaping you can use [`StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml(input)`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html) from [commons-lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/). It is supposedly implemented in a more efficient way there.

Comment: I'd suggest copying this one method instead from commons-lang (you can do it legally since it's ASF2.0 licensed) unless you need any of the additional methods and helper classes provided by commons-lang. Having an entirely new dependency for a single method is bad.

Comment: Yes, but commons-lang has so many methods that are probably useful in most applications and their authors re-write them, not knowing they exist.

Comment: Thanks, this will probably be useful. If I'm not mistaken, the project already uses apache commons as dependency for Solr. I'll look into it :)

Comment: I know this is old, but I couldn't find anywhere else that showed a simple way to fix a string like this. If you add apache `commons-lang3` and try to use `StringEscapeUtils` you will find it is deprecated now. You can still use this, but the non deprecated way is done by also add apache's `commons-text` library, and use the `StringEscapeUtils` class located there. (If using modules, to add the text library after import, write `requires commons.text;` to your module-info file)

Answer (score 3):

This is certainly not the most efficient way to do a lot of replacements. Since strings are immutable, each .replace() leads to the construction of a new String object. For the example you give, each call to this function leads to the temporary creation of 6 String objects.

Considering the example you give, the simplest solution is to use an existing library function for HTML entity encoding. Apache commons [StringEscapeUtils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html) is one option. Another one is [HTMLEntities](https://htmlentities.dev.java.net/)

Answer (score 1):

[Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/) has a very efficient [`escapeHtml`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeHtml%28java.lang.String%29) method in its [`StringEscapeUtils`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html) class.

It's fairly smart about it, and doesn't use string replacement in the way you describe, but instead iterates through the characters, replacing characters with appropriate entities as it finds them.

I don't have any benchmarks handy, but if this stuff is on the critical path of your code, you would be wiese to use this off-the-shelf, faster solution.

Answer (score 1):

Each call to replace returns a new String. Each time you call this function, you are essentially creating four copies of Strings which are going to be immediately discarded. If input is large enough, this can be wasteful.

I would suggest revising your algorithm so that instead of performing N `replace` operations (which needs to scan the String each time), you only scan the list once:

```
//psuedocode
Map<Char, String> replacements = new HashMap<String, String>();
replacements.put("&", "&amp;");
replacements.put(">", "&gt;");
...
private String htmlEscape(String input) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(input.length());
    for (char c: sb.toCharArray()) {
    if (replacements.containsKey(c)) {
        sb.append(replacements.get(c));
    else {
        sb.append(c);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: I had already changed my implementation to check whether or not a certain character is in the string, hoping an if is faster then just doing it... (Don't have the results yet, but I'll probably use the StringEscapeUtils as suggested by others)

Answer (score 1):

It's much easier and more standard to use http://commons.apache.org/lang/. It's very easy and simple.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach with multiple replace methods could be slow.

Look at [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/)'s [StringEscapeUtils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html) for a speedy implementation of escaping HTML entities.

Answer (score 0):

The general algorithm for `String.replace` is a little complicated, but it shouldn't be that bad. Looking at the code, it is in fact implemented using regex so wont be fast - ick.

Obviously, you can write much faster code by iterating through character by character. Possibly working out the exact length first.

You might want to consider how characters outside of`[ -~]` are handled. You might also want to use a library which has already implemented the functionality.

Answer (score 0):

For the casual reader, there is a new player in the Html escape field: [unbescape](http://www.unbescape.org/).

An unescape operation on HTML code can be done like this:

```
final String unescapedText = HtmlEscape.unescapeHtml(escapedText);
```