# How namedparameter query blocks SQL injection

Tags: java, hibernate

I have seen the HQL SQL injection topic at [How to prevent SQL Injection in hibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14102334/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-hibernate). But I could not understand how does`Query.setParameter("<parameter name>",<parameter value>)`

eliminate SQL injection, 
If a malicious user passes`true = true`  to following HQL,`String hqlString = "from Item item where name= '"+nameValue+"'";`

then he can pass it to`query.setString("name"+ nameValue)` also!
Does setString() and all of its sister methods have any filter to check SQL injection?

Comment: `Query` in hibernate exactly like a `PreparedStatement` in conventional jdbc . It actually `Builds` your query and excutes

Answer (score 1):

The JDBC or Hibernate driver will escape this data appropriately before the query is executed; making sure that data is used just as data.

Before executing query, the driver will escape characters like the following:

1. **;**  (Query delimiter.)
2. **'**  (Character data string delimiter.)
3. **--**  (Comment delimiter.)

Comment: I was hoping for an actual attack, e.g. the malicious user passes in `' OR '1'='1` for `nameValue`.

Comment: In this case driver will escape '  character and the value will be like this OR 1=1, and here there is sql injection

Comment: OK, I think we should check what happen if logical operators, SQL operators like LIKE are placed.

Comment: in case of logical operators, you should pass another character to make sql injection, and driver will escape these characters, so logical operator will consider as data not operator.