# Unable to fix SQL Injection: Hibernate,Using veracode tool,how to fix it?

Tags: java, hibernate, session, sql-injection

I am developing an application using hibernate. When I try to create a Login page, The problem of SQL Injection arises,I'm Using Veracode as scanning analyser.

I have the following code:

```
Session session = getSession();
HashMap<String, String> parameters =  new HashMap<String, String>();
String finalValue = _helper.constructSearchSQLQuery(searchCriteria, session, parameters);
SQLQuery sqlQuery = session.createSQLQuery(finalValue);
sqlQuery.addScalar("requestId", Hibernate.LONG);
Set<String> keys = parameters.keySet();
```

At place of SQLQuery sqlQuery=session  showing sql injection .Please help me how to fix this.

Comment: Consider using the Criteria API or HQL / Hibernate Query Language.

Comment: You are giving an sql string into the method. Use parameters instead.

Comment: Also you could try session.createSQLQuery().setParameter() which should be safe.

Comment: Could you please change my source code if possible here so that i can understand easily.

Comment: @LaurentiuL, Showing some error.

Comment: @khanam When i say setParameter, i don't mean copy code as it is. I mean set your parameters via the setParameter method.

Comment: @LaurentiuL. I'm new to Hibernate so im seeking help.Could you please guide me where to change.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to prevent SQL Injection in hibernate?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14102334/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-hibernate)

Comment: @LaurentiuL., i changed the code  as follows,is it right way?  Query sqlQuery = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(
                    finalQuery);
            ((SQLQuery) sqlQuery).addScalar("requestId", Hibernate.LONG);

Comment: I don't know. Not without the big picture. Where this is used, where it's called from, and how constructSearchSQLQuery looks. Don't start posting it all for me. I mentioned my prefered approach. Good luck with your research