# Spring JPA @Query and @Param string escaping (sql injection)

Tags: java, spring, jpa

Good Afternoon

I believe the usage of `org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query` in combination with `org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param` prevents a SQL injection above these parameters.
For example:

```java
@Query("DELETE User c WHERE c.issuer = :issuer AND c.subject = :subject")
    void deleteByIssSub(@Param("issuer") String issuer, @Param("subject") String subject);
```

should be secure. Please correct me, if I am wrong.

Now I'm looking for documentation, which describes, that the usages of @Param in combination with @Query prevent SQL injection (throw string escaping).
But I don't find this documentation.

Am I wrong?

T

Answer (score 1):

Does this help?
[How to prevent SQL Injection with JPA and Hibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14102334/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-with-jpa-and-hibernate/54122517)

By default

**when you are using arguments ( =: )**

and

**when you are setting parameters** **( .setParameter("issuer", issuer) )**

in your code reduces changes of SQL injection to 0, because you are building a query through your code, you are not allowing a user to send any query to the database in altered form, the only thing that he can send are arguments, and only expected arguments.

https://mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-parameter-binding-examples/

As long you avoid building dynamic queries with String concatenation you will be safe, but if you really need to use dynamic queries, you need to use Criteria API instead.

EDIT:
No one can guarantee that for you because and I quote From the OWASP page:
"Hibernate does not grant immunity to SQL Injection, one can misuse the API as they please."
So no one will say that it is 100% bulletproof because people can code and use API as it was not supposed to be used or designed.
https://owasp.org/www-community/Hibernate#Security_Implications

Who is OWASP?
The OWASP® Foundation works to improve the security of software through its community-led open-source software projects, hundreds of chapters worldwide, tens of thousands of members, and by hosting local and global conferences.

No matter how much a car might be safe, the manufacturer will never say "our car is uncrashable", they will just state that it is really safe. The same goes for security. Nothing is 100% safe with the human factor involved.

Comment: Thank you, but this isn't what I'm looking for. I'm looking for a documentation or an API, where I can see that @ Query and @ Param is safe to use.
Something like a proof. Not just a answer in a forum or a reference to the similar setParameter method...
I found the documentation saying, that setParameter is save: https://www.baeldung.com/sql-injection#1parameterized-queries

Comment: I will update my answer just to provide you more info of why you cannot find any proof in the docs. Also, Baeldung is not documentation, it is a site where programmers with a green light from moderators post their examples in exchange for cash.

Comment: Okay thank you. I understand your point. I was thinking that something like this must be the reason for the missing information.

I don't need a promise, that everything is safe, but I would have a good feeling, when I find a point, where somebody wrote that they know the issue of SQL Injection and they build in some mechanisms to prevent it.
Otherwise I would think the author doesn't care about SQL Injection and passes that responsibility to the programmer, who uses the library.