# org.hibernate.session prepared statement

Tags: java, hibernate, prepared-statement

There must be a way to prepare our SQL queries in hibernate right ?

So we don't end up in code vulnerable to SQL injections like this...

```
public List<Book> findByAutor(String author) {
    String qry = "from Book where author=\'"+author+"\'"; 
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<Book> books = (List<Book>) getCurrentSession().createQuery(qry).list();
    return books; 
}
```

Since the user could input something like :

```
"Paulo Coelho\' or ''='"
```

as author and get all books in our database...

Probably something simple, but I just can't find it on the interwebs :/

Comment: edited, please read again i added an explanation for you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prevention against SQL Injection in Hibernate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4606505/prevention-against-sql-injection-in-hibernate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use something like this where you can `set` the string and `check` it:

```
 String qry = "from Book where author= ?"; 
  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  List<Book> books = (List<Book>) getCurrentSession().createQuery(qry)
  .setString(0, author)
  .list();
```

For more info take a look at this [link](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-parameter-binding-examples/)