# Why WebView doesn't render raw HTML properly?

Tags: android, html, webview

Maybe my question is a kind of stupid question but webview doesn't interpret html tags. I searched but didn't find any problem like this. Please let me know if you have any idea.

This is my code:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Get context of application
        mContext = getActivity().getApplicationContext();

        // Assign layout to fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_product_info, container, false);

        mWebView = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.webView);
        mWebView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.transparent));

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        getDialog().setTitle(mProduct.getName());

        mWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, "<HTML>" + mProduct.getDescription() + "</HTML>", "text/html", "utf-8", null);

    }
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2585012/513413), I downloaded [commons-lang3-3.3.2-bin.zip](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/download_lang.cgi) file added to my lib folder and changed my code to the following. It's working fine now. Hope it helps others.

```
@Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        getDialog().setTitle(mProduct.getName());

        String description = mProduct.getDescription();
        description = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4(description);
        mWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, "<HTML>" + description + "</HTML>", "text/html", "utf-8", null);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, `getDescription()` is returning escaped data. Examine the value that comes back from `getDescription()`. If it contains a lot of `&lt;` and `&gt;`, those are `<` and `>` converted into entity references. You will need to convert those back into `<` and `>`.

Comment: Thanks, based on your thoughts I got idea and fixed my problem.